# how to convert timestamp digits to string, not data or time format

Tags: groovy, timestamp

I need to convert timestamp digits to string, for example, 15126..., into string format,  I need it still look like digits 15126..., but in string format, not in any date or time format.

I tried intValue, just got error. All I found else is converting timestamp to date format like 2015-05... or vice versa, didn't find a scenario like mine. Would appreciate if anyone can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: What about `toString`? `Long.toString(15126L)`

Comment: Do you mean `String.valueOf(15126)`?

Comment: what is the datatype and format of your `timestamp`? can you give an example? If it is type `long` then you can simple do this `String time = yourTimestampValue`

Comment: toString will turn the timestamp from 154586... to 2018-05-...

Comment: valueOf will generate error

Comment: the timestamp was get by new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By `Timestamp`, I'm assuming you mean java.sql.Timestamp.

Easiest way I can think of to do what you're asking is

```
Timestamp time = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())

long seconds = time.toInstant().getEpochSecond()

println seconds
```

Comment: Glad to hear :) Can you upvote and accept the answer then?